# Issues with importing from submodules

Tags: python, git

I've got a project with the following structure:

```
\main_model
    __init__.py
    main.py
    \second_module
        __init__.py
        second.py
        \third_module
            __init__.py
            third.py
```

`second_module` and `third_module` are both Git submodules used as libraries by many other projects.

The first line of `main.py` is an import statement: `from main_model.second_module import second`
And the first line of `second.py` is too: `from second_module.third_module import third`

Running `main.py` raises an error with the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/main_model/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main_model.second_module import func_a, func_b
  File "/main_model/second_module/second.py", line 1, in <module>
    from third_module.third import func_c, func_d
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'third_module'
```

So evidently I would need to amend the import statement in `second.py` to be `from main_model.second_module.third_module import third`. I can't do that, though, because `second_module` is a standalone submodule.

Is there a consistent way of structuring the imports, or modifying PYTHONPATH, that would allow the same import syntax from all levels?

Comment: "I can't do that, though, because second_module is a standalone submodule." then it should be installed as such. The module has to be in the path somehow.

Comment: The PYHTONPATH should only contain the top one, then do absolute import ie from the top `from main_mode...` or relative ones `from .second_module.third_module`

Comment: I've tried relative imports and I get "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package".

@juanpa.arrivillaga Can you tell me what you mean by "installed as such"?

Comment: @triphook when you install a package, e.g. `pip install somelibrary` that adds the installed modules to your `site-packages` directory, which is why you can `import` them from anywhere.

Comment: This isn't going to be installed, it'll be deployed in an AWS EC2, so I don't have that option

Comment: @triphook it can still be installed in an AWS EC2 instance, that doesn't make any sense. Presumably, you are deploying some docker image?

Comment: “Copy-paste” Python package nesting is fundamentally broken, and Git submodules aren’t going to fix it (or much of anything else).

Comment: Could you change the import statement to just `from main_model import second_module` then use second_module.second? Does that work?